# how to insert textbox value into gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript

I've two text box , one button and grid view.

What I want is simple, whenever i click on button the value from text box will insert into grid view.

I need javascript for this b'cs i'm new in javascript.

Comment: add some code and markup you have

Comment: Also check this article, you don't need to "copy" anything http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Comment: And if you could, add a description of what is working and what is not working. This will help us understand which portion of the code may be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Last weekend while helping one of my friends on his project, I needed to perform row level client side operation on asp.net gridview. Firstly I googled for finding something similar to “formulae in excel” for asp gridview. When I failed to find something good I decided to go with javascript to perform client side operation on individual gridview rows.

My scenario was of invoice sheet generation, where need was of addition of rows(one for each product selected) dynamically and then perform some calculation like displaying row wise total. On click of Add button new record for item selected in drop down is added(this is done from server side code). Here user can enter values in any of the textboxes. And system has to update values in Total Excessible Value column text box(see image below) accordingly.

For this I wrote two plain javascript functions and called them on onchange event of textbox. Below are grid view and jquery code that I used.

(Click to enlarge)

GridView that I used was below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvInvoiceItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="true"
        OnRowCommand="gdvInvoiceItems_RowCommand">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No items added yet.
        EmptyDataTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No.">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnItemId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                ItemTemplate>
            asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description of Goods" ItemStyle-CssClass="description">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                        CssClass="txtDescStyle">asp:TextBox>
                ItemTemplate>
            asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity(Net)" ItemStyle-CssClass="quantity">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' onchange="javascript:Multiply(this, this.value)">asp:TextBox>
                ItemTemplate>
            asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value Per Unit" ItemStyle-CssClass="value">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PerUnitValue") %>' onchange="javascript:Multiply(this, this.value)">asp:TextBox>
                ItemTemplate>
            asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Exesible Value" ItemStyle-CssClass="exesiblevalue">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalExeValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Total") %>' CssClass="TotalExeValue">asp:TextBox>
                ItemTemplate>
            asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnRemove" runat="server" Text="Remove" ItemStyle-CssClass="remove">
                    asp:LinkButton>
                ItemTemplate>
            asp:TemplateField>
        Columns>
    asp:GridView>
```

JavaScript code used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      //This method is called when quantity/cost textbox looses focus with some change in content
      function Multiply(element, val)
      {
          var otherElementName = '';
          var finalElementName = '';

          //id of calling element i.e, quantity/cost textbox
          var elementName = element.id;

        //get second element, i.e., get quantity if change is in cost and vice-versa
          if(endsWith(elementName, "txtQuantity"))
          {
              otherElementName = elementName.replace("txtQuantity", "txtValue");
          }
          else if(endsWith(elementName, "txtValue"))
          {
              otherElementName = elementName.replace("txtValue", "txtQuantity");
          }    
          var otherElement = document.getElementById(otherElementName);

          //get textbox where final value is to be displayed
        finalElementName = elementName.replace("txtValue", "txtTotalExeValue")         
          var finalElement = document.getElementById(finalElementName);
          finalElement.value = otherElement.value * val;
      }

      //checks if given string ends with given suffix
      function endsWith(str, suffix) {
        return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    }

    script>
```

Highlighted lines onchange="javascript:Multiply(this, this.value)" are the one that are doing the magic. This onchange event doesn't comes in intellisense but it works.

Answer (score 0):

That is what you need, no need for extra js function, use CompareValidator.
Template field should has EditItemTemplate and some control bound ( `<%# Bind(...) %>`) to field in the data source

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Units In Stock">
    <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="editUnitsInStock" Runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Bind("UnitsInStock") %>' Columns="4"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator2" Runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must provide a valid integer for Units In Stock."
            ControlToValidate="editUnitsInStock" 
            Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: sorry to say but i want script for storing textbox value into asp.net gridview...i want to store data into gridview client side so i required javascript for this.

Comment: Is it supposed to persist? if yes you indeed need server side, otherwise GridView won't remember value you just hacked in it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code. It will help to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function copyTextValue(bf) {
                if(bf.checked)
                      var text1 = document.getElementById("Name1").value;
                else
                      text1='';
                document.getElementById("Name2").value = text1;
                document.getElementById("Name3").value=text1;

                }
        </script>
</head>
<body>


       <input type="checkbox" name="check1" onchange="copyTextValue(this);"/>
<input id="Name1"><input id="Name2"><input id="Name3">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry to say i already know this but i want script for storing textbox value into asp.net gridview...